# PPTP works on Debian 6.0 but not Debian 5.0 or CentOS?

Tags: centos, debian, vpn, pptp

I installed PPTP successfully on a Debian 6.0 64-bit machine, and tried to mimic the installation on both a Debian 5.0 machine, and a CentOS machine. However, I get error codes on connecting with both of those latter machines. The error codes are: 809 and 619.  They differ as I hit the "retry" button.

I don't understand why it works on Debian 6.0, while the other two don't, even though they have the exact same configuration.

I already verified the ports are open and reachable externally. I did the following to install the VPN software:

> Step 1: Installing pptpd – the pptpd is the daemon that runs the pptp
>   server. To install this just use apt-get:
>
> ```
> $ aptitude install pptpd
> ```
>
> Step 2: Next you will need to modify the pptpd.conf
>
> ```
> $ vim /etc/pptpd.conf
> ```
>
> Then scroll down to the bottom and modify the following lines with the
>   subnets you would like assigned:
>
> ```
> # (Recommended)
> #localip 192.168.0.1
> #remoteip 192.168.0.234-238,192.168.0.245
> # or
> localip 10.0.0.1
> remoteip 10.0.0.21-41,10.0.0.51
> ```
>
> (Recommended) Edit /etc/ppp/options and add google's opendns addresses
>
> ```
> ms-dns 8.8.8.8
> ms-dns 8.8.4.4
> ```
>
> Step 3: The vpn server is now configured and now you must setup
>   authenticated users:
>
> ```
> $ vim /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
> ```
>
> The config file is very straight forward and I have an example of a
>   user included:
>
> ```
> # Secrets for authentication using CHAP
> # client server secret IP addresses
> johndoe pptpd johndoepassword *
> ```
>
> Step 4: When pptpd was installed it started automatically so we will need
>   to restart it to apply the changes:
>
> ```
> $ /etc/init.d/pptpd restart
> ```
>
> Now, if you would like to add internet access over this vpn, you can
>   do this:
>
> ```
> $ vim /etc/sysctl.conf
> ```
>
> and find the line for ipv4 forwarding and make sure it = 1:
>
> Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
>
> ```
> net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
> ```
>
> Then use iptables to get the net forwarded:
>
> ```
> $ /sbin/iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
> $ /sbin/iptables --table nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
> ```

Update1:
Log file sais the following: Couldnt open the /dev/ppp device no such file or directory

[snapshot of log](http://i1132.photobucket.com/albums/m577/kakaboeie/putty-vpn-error.png)

Update2:
It seems the kernel is the problem, I received the message "sorry this system lacks ppp kernel support" and since this is a vps running op OpenVZ I can't alter the kernel (OpenVZ kernel is shared). Not wonder the Debian6 one did work, that's a dedicated server. I guess I have to get openvpn working after all :(

Comment: Things that would help your question: log messages, your exact configuration and software version on all machines involved, and a citation for that howto that makes up the vast majority of your question.

Comment: Oh, and try OpenVPN instead of PPTP -- much less insanity (or at least different insanity).

Comment: @womble The how-to is here; http://www.larmeir.com/2010/03/setting-up-a-pptp-vpn-server-on-debian-and-ubuntu/ -> I wouldn't know where to find log files containing useful info, and what other configuration would you need to know? I did try openvpn before I tried this, couldn't get it working either.

Comment: Add information to the question, not as comments.  If you can't find log files, you really should try superuser instead of this site.

Comment: @womble I found the log files.

Comment: You should place your solution as an answer, and accept it.  That way others can learn from your experience (via Google, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the kernel is the problem, I received the message "sorry this system lacks ppp kernel support" and since this is a vps running op OpenVZ I can't alter the kernel (OpenVZ kernel is shared). Not wonder the Debian6 one did work, that's a dedicated server. I guess I have to get openvpn working after all :(